# Terraform : How to send instance IPs to aws_instances after provisioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Example code

```
resource "aws_instance" "A" {
 #provisioning declarations
}

resource "aws_instance" "B" {
  #provisioning declarations
}

# Crux of problem : This should run after all instances are provisioned sending all IPs to each
resource "null_resource" "send_instance_ips" {
  
  depends_on = [aws_instance.A, aws_instance.B] 
  
  for_each = { for idx, instance in [aws_instance.A, aws_instance.B]: idx=> instance}
  
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "admin-user"
    private_key = file("~/id_rsa")
    host = each.value.public_ip
  }
  
  provisioner "remote-exec" { 
     inline = [
      "echo ${aws_instance.A.*.private_ip} > a_ip.txt",
      "echo ${aws_instance.B.*.private_ip} > b_ip.txt"
    ]
  }     
}
```

**Question :** How do you invoke a module/provision to send data to instances after provisioned

**Issues I get when trying to create a plan**

```
Error: 2 problems:

- Invalid template interpolation value: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
- Invalid template interpolation value: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: Haven't noticed its null `null_resource`, sorry. So you want to run it in the loop? What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Yes i would like to loop the connection over all IPs generated from all the created instances. I've included the error/issue above

Comment: Answer updated and undeleted. Please have a look.

Comment: How did it go with the `null_resource`? I see you made a new question regarding this, thus not sure if this one did not work?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I think I was being a bonehead. I had read up on 'each' and 'for_each' nuances

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your instance in `null_resource` using `for_each`. For example (example tested on `ubuntu` instances, so you have to adjust connection details to your own):

```
resource "null_resource" "send_instance_ips" {
  
  for_each = { for idx, instance in [aws_instance.A,aws_instance.B]:
               idx=>instance}
  
  connection {
    user        = "ubuntu"
    host        = each.value.public_ip
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
  }  
  
  provisioner "remote-exec" { 
     inline = [
        "echo ${each.value.private_ip} > a_ip.txt"
    ]
  }     
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if you need all IP form all instances in each instance, or just current instance IP in the loop. I chose to use the second option in the example. But the example could also be adjusted to use all IPs, but it would require modifications of your `inline` part.